# PDO with WHERE and array together

Tags: mysql, arrays, pdo

i have a big problem on hands, lets see:

```php
public  function funccc(){
$in = implode(',', $_GET[cat]); //  $_GET[cat] values is like 1,2,3,4,5,6
$cons = DB::getConn()->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE column=? OR column=? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
$cons->execute(array($in),array($in));  // here's the problem <<<<< how can i execute a array inside a array on pdo?
$question=$cons->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $question['pgt'];}
```

if someone knows how can i fix that,please help me.

Comment: [How can I create a prepared statement for IN () operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15991146/285587)